# How to give input to compiled C program on Mac from terminal

Tags: c, macos, terminal

I am trying to solve an assignment question - "Write a program to copy its input to its output, replacing each string of one or more blanks by a single blank". After writing the code, I am trying to compile it on a Mac terminal. I know how to compile using gcc command.

How do I give input from terminal to see what the output is?

The code that I have tried:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int c, inspace;

    inspace = 0;

    while((c = getchar()) != EOF)
    {
        if(c == ' ')
        {
            if(inspace ==0)
            {
                inspace = 1;
                putchar(c);
            }
        }

        if(c != ' ')
        {
            inspace = 0;
            putchar(c);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Heh? You need to _run_ the code.

Comment: Yeah. You're asking us how to compile it, then telling us that you've compiled it already.

Comment: `./a.out < test.txt`

Comment: `gcc -o program program.c` and then `./program < program.c` — provide the programs source as the standard input.  You should have spaces in your program source; your program should show you the output without any  repeated spaces — if it is correct, of course.

Comment: Jonathan's advice is correct. Compile with `gcc -o program program.c` and run with `./program < someDataFileToTest`

Comment: Actually, you could also simply run `./program` and then type your text with single and multiple spaces, rather than feeding a file to the program.  You'd need to type control-D at the beginning of a line to indicate EOF (or type it twice to indicate EOF without a newline as the last character).  You could also interrupt the program with control-C.

Answer (score 1):

Use

`gcc program.c`

then run using :

```
./a.out
```

don't give enter, first type in some characters using your keyboard, then press enter.  You'd need to type control-D at the beginning of a line to indicate EOF (or type it twice to indicate EOF without a newline as the last character). You could also interrupt the program with control-C.